# quality profile in gradle

Tags: gradle, profile, sonarqube

how to include quaility profile in gradle? when i try to include sonar plugin like this

```
apply plugin: "sonar-runner"

sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
        property "sonar.host.url", ""
        property "sonar.login", "r"
        property "sonar.password", ""
        property "sonar.jdbc.url", ""
        property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        property "sonar.jdbc.username", "r"
        property "sonar.jdbc.password", ""
        property "sonar.profile", "test"
        property "sonar.projectName", "liki"
        property "sonar.language", "java"
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
        property "sonar.binaries", "build";
    }
}
```

i have got in sonar new project, but my quiluty profile not included

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the above example the following line sets what quality profile to be used during the analysis:

```
property "sonar.profile", "test"
```

You have to change "test" to your quality profile name that you want to use. If you want to use the default, then remove (or comment out) this line from your gradle build file.